# How do I give Bar data from another file?

Tags: reactjs

barChart.js

```js
class BarChart extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <Bar />
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

main.js

```js
import BarChart from './barChart';

return (
    <BarChart data={data} />
)
```

The bar chart shows properly but the data I assign doesn't work, anyone might know how can I give the Bar the data from main.js file?

Answer (score 0):

i am change `barChart.js`

```
export const BarChart =({data})=> {
    console.log(data);
      return (
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <Bar />
        </div>
      )
    
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: It doesn't work. Keep in mind `data` is not defined in `barChart.js`

Comment: I'm checking now